# How can get values from php array using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I trying to get data from php array and put in java-script variable. Follwoing are the php arrays.

### Array Name

```
Array
(
    [0] => username
    [1] => byusers
)
```

### Array Value

```
Array
(
    [0] => user
    [1] => 1
)
```

### What I have Try tried

Get php array value in javascript variable

```
var DATATABLE_SEARCH_NAMES      = new Array( "<?php echo (is_array($DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_NAMES)) ? $DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_NAMES['names'] : 0;?>");
var DATATABLE_SEARCH_VALUES     = new Array( "<?php echo (is_array($DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_VALUE)) ? $DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_VALUE['values'] : 0;?>");
```

Comment: @u_mulder how can use it...?

Comment: If you're developing a web service, then this server response will automatically appear as an 'object' using javascript. then you can use it like this: `username.user`

Comment: json_decode( $arrayToDecode ); # converts arrays to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you ask, it is just a case of converting the PHP arrays to a form that javascript can understand. You can use `json_encode()` to do that.

```
$DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_NAMES = array('username','byusers');
$DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_VALUE = array('user', 1);

$js1 = json_encode($DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_NAMES);
$js2 = json_encode($DATATABLE_SEARCH_DATA_VALUE);

//echo $js1.PHP_EOL;
//echo $js2.PHP_EOL;

echo "<script>\n";
echo 'var names = ' . $js1 . ";\n";
echo 'var values = ' . $js2 . ";\n";
echo "</script>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

say, you have a PHP array as this:

```
$arr = array("key1"=>"foo","key2"=>"bar");
```

the easiest way to put it to javascript is this:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

ending with a `JSON` object.